# Why is it when I add data into my database it doesn't store the correct time?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a daterange picker to add my start date and time and end date and time. But, I don't know why it doesn't input the correct time. Whenever I add the data, everything else is correct except the time. It outputs it as 12 am even though I chose a different start time and end time.

When I add event data even though I choose a different start date time and end date time it saves the start time and end time as 12 am
[image]

When I view the details everything is correct except for the time. (pls excuse the input element and the time format I will still have to edit that)
[image]

how it appears on calendar
[image]

Event Model

```
class Event extends Model
{

    //
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function eventCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\EventCategory', 'evcat_id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
    protected $fillable = [
        'event_name', 'event_desc', 'event_venue', 'event_status', 'event_start', 'event_finish', 'evcat_id', 'user_id',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

store function in EventController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //

         $this->validate($request, [
            'event_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
            'daterange' => 'required',
        ]);
        $time_start = $request->input('start_time');

        $time_end = $request->input('end_time');

        $tempDate = $request->input('daterange');
        $temp2 = str_replace('-', null, $tempDate);
        $temp2 = str_replace('/', '-', $temp2);
        $temp3 = explode('  ', $temp2);

        $date1 = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $temp3[0]);
        $date2 = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $temp3[1]);

        $event = new event([
            'event_name' => $request->input('event_name'),
            'event_desc' => $request->input('event_desc'),
            'event_venue' => $request->input('event_venue'),
            'event_start' => date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d'),
            'event_finish' => date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d'),
            'event_venue' => $request->input('event_venue'),
            'evcat_id' => $request->input('evcat_id'),
            'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
        ]);

        $event->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'Event Created Successfully');
        return redirect()->route('event.sched');

    }
```

events migration table

```
    {
        Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('event_name');
            $table->string('event_desc')->nullable();
            $table->string('event_venue')->nullable();

            //0 = Ongoing; 1 = Upcoming; 2 = Finished;
            $table->integer('event_status')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('event_start');
            $table->dateTime('event_finish');

            $table->integer('evcat_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        });

        Schema::table('events', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('evcat_id')->references('id')->on('event_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }
```

blade file event.blade.php I used a modal to add data

```
<div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add</strong> Event</h4>
                <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>-->
            </div>
            <form method = "post" action = "{{ url('/sched/add') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="control-label">Event Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control form-white" type="text" name="event_name" id = 'event_name' required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                            <input class="form-control form-white" type="text" name="event_desc" id = 'event_desc' required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="control-label">Venue</label>
                            <input class="form-control form-white"  type="text" name="event_venue" id = 'event_venue' required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="control-label">Start Date - End Date</label>
                            <input type="text" onclick = "getTime()" class="form-control input-daterange-timepicker" id = 'daterange' name="daterange" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="start_time">
                            <input type="hidden" id="end_time">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">

                        <label class="control-label">Choose Event Category</label>
                        <select class="form-control form-white" data-placeholder="Choose a category..." name="evcat_id" id = "evcat_id">
                            @foreach($category as $cat)
                            <option value= '{{$cat->id}}'>{{$cat->ev_category_name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light save-category">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: I dont think it's even storing time into the database as your controller declares `$time_start` and `$time_end` but it's not used since its initization

Comment: To add onto that, your `$event` contains nothing about time and your two date variables don't do anything with it.

Comment: "OP has $time_start = $request->input('start_time'); and $time_end = $request->input('end_time'); it looks like its just missing the merge" hi what do you mean by merge?

Comment: Well since you only have a `m-d-Y`, just make it a `m-d-Y H:i:s` by joining the date and time string together before running it thru `date_create_from_format`

Comment: Also would be helpful to see at least what the server is receiving. Usually those kind of components send the date and time as a single prop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using the format 'm-d-Y' and 'Y-m-d' which does not include the time placeholders. As such, the time will always default to 00:00:00.

To include the time, in your date formating, use 'H:i:s'

example: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

See further formatting info here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: OP has `$time_start = $request->input('start_time');` and `$time_end = $request->input('end_time');` it looks like its just missing the merge